# How to pass multiple value in gitlab cicd variables

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a multiple project in my gitlab repository wherein I do perform multiple commits when it requires.
I have develop a code in python through which I can get report of all the commits done by me in a csv format for all the projects available in gitlab repository as I have hard coded the the project ids in my python code as a LIST.
The Header of the csv file is : Date, submitted, gitlab_url, project, username, subject.

Now I want to run the pipeline manually by setting up an environment variable as 'Project_Ids'
and want to pass some of the project ids as value (More than one project id as a value) so that csv report should get generated for only these projects which has been passed as a value in environment variable.

so My question is , How can I pass multiple project ids as a value in 'Project_Ids' key while running the pipeline manually.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJxCp.png)

```
import gitlab
import os
import datetime
import csv
import re

Project_id_list = ['9427','8401','17937','26813','24899','23729','34779','27638','28600']

headerList = ['Date', 'Submitted', 'Gitlab_url', 'Project', 'Branch', 'Status', 'Username', 'Ticket', 'Subject']

filename = 'mydemo_{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'))

# private token authentication
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://main.gitlab.in.com/', private_token="MLyWwLyEhU2zZjjjhZXog")

gl.auth()

# list all projects


for m in Project_id_list:
    i=0
    if (i<len(Project_id_list)):
        i=+1
    print(m)
    projects = gl.projects.get(m)
    commits = projects.commits.list(all=True, query_parameters={'ref_name': 'master'})

    with open(f"{filename}_{m}.csv", 'w', newline="") as file:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',',
              fieldnames=headerList)
        dw.writeheader()

        for commit in commits:
            print(commit)
            msg = commit.message

            if 'master' in msg or 'LCS-' in msg:
                projectName = projects.path_with_namespace
                branch = 'master'
                status = 'merged'
                date = commit.committed_date.split('T')[0]
                submitted1 = commit.created_at.split('T')[1]
                submitted = submitted1.split('.000')[0]
                Gitlab_url = commit.web_url.split('-')[0]
                username = commit.author_name
                subject = commit.title
                subject1 = commit.message.splitlines()
                print(subject1)
                subject2 = subject1[0:3]
                print(subject2)
                subject3 = '    '.join(subject2)
                print(subject3)
                match = re.search('S-\d+', subject3)
                

                if match:
                    ticket = match.group(0)
                    ticket_url = 'https://.in.com/browse/' + str(ticket)
                    ticket1 = ticket_url
                    dw.writerow({'Date': date, 'Submitted': submitted, 'Gitlab_url': Gitlab_url, 'Project': projectName,
                                 'Branch': branch, 'Status': status, 'Username': username, 'Ticket': ticket1,
                                 'Subject': subject3})
                else:
                    ticket1 = 'Not Found'
                    dw.writerow({'Date': date, 'Submitted': submitted, 'Gitlab_url': Gitlab_url, 'Project': projectName,
                                'Branch': branch, 'Status': status, 'Username': username, 'Ticket': ticket1,
                                'Subject': subject3})
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, images of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @KlausD.
yes , I am editing my post.

Comment: Nit an image. Just copy and paste it.

Comment: @toyotaSupra...done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a space or some other delimiter in the variable value. For example, a string like `123 456 789`

Then in Python, simply parse the variable. For example, using the string `.split` method to split on whitespace.

```py
import os
...
project_ids_variable = os.environ.get('PROJECT_IDS', '') # '123 456 789'
project_ids = project_ids_variable.split() # ['123', '456', '789']
for project_id in project_ids:
    project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
    print(project)
```

Comment: Thanks , It is working
One more doubt regarding the same, Is it possible to create a dropdown in VALUE field so that I will save all project id over there and  then directly select the required project id while running pipeline manually.

Comment: @TheTester You can't create a dropdown, but you can pre-fill a static value (the default) and a helpful text description that will show up in the UI by using the [`value:`  and `description:` keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#variablesdescription) in your YAML.